# Installation Error - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, magento2.4

I am installing Magento 2.4 with my (Magento 2.3 Database), but Now I am getting this error, anyone can guide me or give me any solution how to I can fix this issue ? Please check below screenshot.

Thanks & Regards

[image]

Comment: yes MYSQL has been depricated in 2.4.0 so it uses elastic search 7 as a default search engine you need to configure elatic search...  also if your upgrading from 2.3.5 its better to configure elastic search before upgrading to 2.4.0 as in 2.4.0 its requires an alive node and will not work

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution for this issue: below command is working fine for me.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/fakshop/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=fakshop --db-user=root --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin2 --admin-email=test@email.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=testing123 --language=en_US --currency=AED --timezone=America/Sao_Paulo --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1 --elasticsearch-port=9200
```